# Retrieving online data with a wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm facing a little problem, and I hope that you will have a solution.
I'm using a wcf service to retrieve online data (from yahoo finance).
This service calls an API which connect to yahoo in order to retrieve the data I need.
However, when I call the API, I get the error

> An exception occurred during a `WebClient` request.

I'm calling this service from console application.

I hope that you can help me with this issue.

== Here is the code

```
/* wcf service Interface */
 [ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetData(int value);


    // TODO: Add your service operations here
}

/* the service calls this function which belongs to another c# project */
public String updateDataBase()
{
    DBHandler handler = new DBHandler();
    /* Goes online et retrieve the data, when its called, the exception occurs */
    handler.updateData();
    return "success";

}
```

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: It should be obvious that the code you posted will throw the exception you posted.

Comment: Why? The service implementation will call the method updateDatabase, the exception is thrown when it's reach the line "handler.udpateData()". So can you be more specific please?

I forgot to write that : the method updateDataBase is not writen in the service interface, but in another project which I referenced.

Comment: Then the problem is in the other project, isn't it?

Comment: Sadly it's not. When I call this project directly from a Console application, it works fine. I need to call this other project from a web service because, I will have to use this project in a silverlight application, and this API cannot be compile for silverlight. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by running visual studio as Administrator.

Thank you.